# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null when i want to add new elements to my database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a form to create new post from the auth users however im getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"
and cant seem to know why
my script is at the end of the HTML and its an external file, I've used eventListener in other places and it work just fine. I've even checked for spelling errors but to no avail.

```
 const createForm = document.querySelector('#create-form');
  createForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
   console.log("hey you clicked p")
     e.preventDefault();
      db.collection('guides').add({
       title: createForm['title'].value,
        content: createForm['content'].value
   }).then(() => {
    // close the create modal & reset form
     const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-create');
      M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
       createForm.reset();
   }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
    });
 });
```

this is my html

```
<!-- CREAT A NEW POST -->
<div id="modal-create" class="modal">
   <form class="modal-content animate"  method="post">
    <div>
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('modal-create').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Create Post</h4><br/>
    <form id="create-form">
      <div class="input-field">
        <input type="text" id="title" required>
        <label for="title">The Subject</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <textarea id="content" class="materialize-textarea" required></textarea>
        <label for="content">The Content</label>
      </div>
      <button class="btn yellow darken-2 z-depth-0">Create</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your script tag relative to the HTML body?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, [nested forms are not allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) "___Permitted content__: Flow content, but not containing `<form>` elements_". Rename the outer form tag to div, then your code probably works. Browsers are actually removing the nested form elements, but preserving the content of those forms, that's why JS can't find the form with the given id.

Comment: yes it was the first form that caused the problem thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a form within a form, which is bad and I think in this case, a typo

Try removing `<form class="modal-content animate"  method="post">` and see if that clears things up

Comment: this will just undo my CSS its not effecting the code

Comment: thank you it work just fine just had to change the first form into a div

Answer (score 0):

```js
const createForm = document.querySelector('#form_submit');
  createForm.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   console.log("hey you clicked p")
     e.preventDefault();
      db.collection('guides').add({
       title: createForm['title'].value,
        content: createForm['content'].value
   }).then(() => {
    // close the create modal & reset form
     const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-create');
      M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
       createForm.reset();
   }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
    });
 });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!-- CREAT A NEW POST -->
<div id="modal-create" class="modal">
   <form class="modal-content animate"  method="post">
    <div>
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('modal-create').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Create Post</h4><br/>
    <form id="create-form">
      <div class="input-field">
        <input type="text" id="title" required>
        <label for="title">The Subject</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <textarea id="content" class="materialize-textarea" required></textarea>
        <label for="content">The Content</label>
      </div>
      <button type='submit' class="btn yellow darken-2 z-depth-0" id="form_submit">Create</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this it won't give that error

Comment: this did remove the problem however the database is not being updated with the new content that I've entered and also the console.log is not showing the "you clicked p" which means the problem still exist